# Save Previous Chosen Values In Dropdown Menu In tableOutput In RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

My current app shows the `tableOutput` based on the chosen values in the dropdown (**"Group"**). The problem is that the `tableOutput` only shows the data from just one chosen value from the dropdown. However, I would like to see all the values that are chosen from the dropdown. For instance, If a user selects Groups A and B, it will show 3 rows (there are 2 rows for Group A and 1 row for Group B). How would one do this?

Any advice would be helpful!

Here is a reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

df <- data.frame("Group" = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), "Number" = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           pickerInput("groupInput", "Group:",
             choices = unique(df$Group),
             multiple = T)
           )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("wholeData")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$groupInput)
    df %>% 
      filter(Group == input$groupInput)
  })
  
  output$wholeData <- renderTable({
    dataset <- data()
    req(dataset)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Would `filter(Group %in% input$groupInput)` provide what you need?

Comment: You need `filter(Group %in% input$groupInput)`

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for your help.